# Getting data from a webpage with login requirement Java

Tags: java, authentication, htmlunit

So recently I decided to teach myself how to get data from webpages. I managed to get data from JSON from a different webpage but when I try to copy everything from this website, it doesn't show the data I actually need.

The page I am trying is for example: http://www.tremorgames.com/index.php?action=shop&page=2 (You might need to register). The data I am trying to get is for example game name/ price or stock, if I can get one then I will be able to get all.

The problem is that Dev tools shows the code but when I try to copy everything to a file using Java, it doesn't show most part of the code.

(I tried with Jsoup as well and it doesn't work either).
This is what I have for copying from webpages:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.tremorgames.com/index.php?action=shop&page=2");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int read;
    char[] chars = new char[1024];
    while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
        buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

    return buffer.toString();
} finally {
    if (reader != null)
        reader.close();
}
```

And as I said, I am trying to learn so any pointers are welcome(I've been searching for a while until I gave up and wrote the rest of the code).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Java to pull data from a webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159118/using-java-to-pull-data-from-a-webpage)

Comment: As I said, I have been searching for an answer for a while, that is not it, I've looked at it before.

Comment: _might need to register_, this tells me that the stream you get from the site in your browser depends on authentication. Now you don't implement this in your Java code. Nor do you have the implementation of cookies which the site may use. Differs everywhere. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091053/how-to-login-in-web-site-using-java) discusses "How to login in web site using Java". Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out but I am not sure it is the solution since when I used Jsoup it gave me an error that it can't access the link until I logged in. But maybe this is different. I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: This code implies a very simplistic view of how dynamic HTML works.  I strongly suggest you get Firebug (Firefox) or the equivalent debug tools for other browsers and study what actually happens when you visit the page.  In general (except for 1990's static HTML websites) you cannot fetch a page in a single simple GET.  It's A LOT more complex.

Comment: After you see what actually happens your next question will be _"How do I know to do all that stuff?"_ to which the answer is "implement a complete browser".  And then you'll understand why modern browsers are such large complex pieces of software.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am sure that my view is currently simplistic but keep in mind I have been looking into the subject for a bit more than 24 hours. And that is without the fact that I have an upcoming exam in assembly in a week. I certainly intend to look into the subject more though.

Comment: @BoobyTrap Sorry if that came across wrong. As I reread it I see the tone isn't quite what I intended. The gist is correct however. There's an awful lot going on when you visit a page, including up to hundreds of additional GETs, POSTs and then dynamic requests and DOM modifications via JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I finished this a while ago but forgot to answer my own question.
I used HtmlUnit for this because it looked like it was the most simple to do.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;  
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput;  
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;  
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
```

In order to get data from that certain webpage, I needed to log into the website first. For this I needed to start a web client.
The thing to remember about this is the need to use the same web client so you will need initiate WebClient in the method that will call the login method(This method will also later send the WebClient to get data and anything else you might need).

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); //Initiate a WebClient variable.  
webClient = tremorLogin(webClient);
```

Then in tremorLogin I will log into the website and return the client back to webClient variable.

```
//Login into Tremor Games and return the client(Saves the cookies).
private static WebClient tremorLogin(WebClient webClient) throws Exception
{
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.tremorgames.com/"); //Load page at the STRING address.
    HtmlInput username = currentPage.getElementByName("loginuser"); //Find element called loginuser for username
    username.setValueAttribute(user); //Set value for username
    HtmlInput password = currentPage.getElementByName("loginpassword"); //Find element called loginpassword for password
    password.setValueAttribute(pass); //Set value for password
    HtmlSubmitInput submitBtn = currentPage.getElementByName("Submit"); //Find element called Submit to submit form.
    currentPage = submitBtn.click(); //Click on the button.

    return webClient;
}
```

The loginuser text is what the text field of the user name is called when you check the source code of the website.

```
HtmlInput username = currentPage.getElementByName("loginuser");
```

The loginpassword text is what the text field of the password is called when you check the source code of the website.

```
HtmlInput password = currentPage.getElementByName("loginpassword");
```

user is your username(String type) and pass is your password(String type)

```
username.setValueAttribute(user);  
password.setValueAttribute(pass);
```

After writing the username and password you will need to click on the submit button and for this you will need to find the name of the button in the website's source code(Same way as username and password text fields. After you have found the name of the button, you will need to click on it which is the second line.

```
 HtmlSubmitInput submitBtn = currentPage.getElementByName("Submit"); //Find element called Submit to submit form.
currentPage = submitBtn.click(); //Click on the button.
```

Once you return this, your web client is saved in the original method and later you can get all the data from there or anything else you might want to get from the website.
In the original method you might have something like

```
HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.tremorgames.com/index.php?action=shop&searchterm=steam&search_category=5&sort=price_asc&page=1");
String pageSource = currentPage.asXml();
```

After you have the website as xml in pageSource, you will have exactly the same text/code you see in developer tools and later you just need to search through it for the data you need.

Hope this will help and save time for people.